# testing urllib2 application, http responses loaded from files

Tags: python, urllib2

My python application makes many http requests to many urls using urllib2.  I would like to build a unit test suite to test my data parsing and error handling code.

I have a directory full of test data, with a number of files, each file containing a single http response, with headers and response data.  (using curl -i)  In some cases, these files contain http error messages (needed to test the error handling)

Ideally, I would like to create a mock object to replace urllib2.urlopen and return a mock response object.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to have urllib2 load an HTTP response directly from a file and have urllib2 parse this data to create the appropriate response object (as if the response was read from a url.

I tried using url's constructed with "file://" protocol, however the http response headers at the top of the file were not read nor parsed properly.

Alternatively I am considering writing a small web server class to serve the test files, however this seems like a little more work than I'd like.  It would be easier to have urllib2 somehow reconstruct the response object from the http responses I've already saved in files (without having to build a web server to serve them again)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to mock a subset of `httplib.HTTPConnection` (call the resulting class `mockcon` for concreteness in the following) and add a handler using it and subclassing `HTTPHandler` (to use in `build_opener` -- the subclassing means it can *replace* `HTTPHandler` that `build_opener` uses by default):

```
class MockHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):

    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(mockcon, req)
```

The mockcon class must supply the methods `do_open` call -- several can be dummies (i.e. accept and ignore arbitrary args and kwds and do nothing):

```
set_debuglevel
_set_tunnel
request
```

(may be interested in the 2nd arg of `request`, as it gives the "selector" part of the URL).

The `__init__` method of `mockcon` gets the host part of the URL as the first arg (i.e., first after `self` of course) and should ignore following kwds (used to set a timeout).

The `get_response` method of `mockcon` (no args, beyond of course `self`) must return an http response object -- i.e., a file-like readable object which also has attributes `.msg`, `.status`, and `.reason`, and a method `get_full_url()` to return the URL.

You could use an actual `httplib.HTTPResponse` instance for the latter role, but you must initialize it with one mock/dummy arg that has a `makefile` argument (ignores its args and kwds and returns whatever), and, right after initializing it, reset its `.fp` argument to be a `rb` open file giving exactly the bytes that a real HTTP response would receive on its socket.

I think that building a full-fledged mock for the whole `urllib2.urlopen` call might be simpler than this attempt to reuse most of the functionality of `urllib2` (and `httplib` which it uses internally), though perhaps not quite as simple as the "local web server" approach which you appear to think is more work.  But it's worth considering all the three approaches (the mock would surely be most-lightweight/fast in operation, the local web server slowest... and would also require somehow modifying the URLs by prefixing an `http://localhost:someport/` to them, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The server approach is definitely not more work, it's probably the easiest and least work of all your alternatives.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html

A 7 line python program that when run from a certain directory will serve up all the files(and, recursively, any files in subdirectories) over HTTP.

You could probably have your unit test code start and stop the server so you don't need to leave it running even when not testing.

Comment: Although easy for simple tests, it's usually not a good approach to start a server running (a new process too) for *unit tests*, mocking external entities and functionality is the best approach. For many other types of testing, this is a good option. A reason not too strong to downvote though!

Comment: I agree, a proper mock solution would work better overall. I was only responding to the statement that it would be too much work to do that. In terms of getting up and running quickly, it's probably the easiest thing to do. It's definitely not the best in the long run, I wasn't arguing that at all